# Azure Search Lucene Query Incorrect Result

Tags: azure, lucene, full-text-search, azure-cognitive-search

I am currently using Azure Search to bring back images stored in blob storage, based off filters that are passed in by the user. Below is my Azure Search, which I thought should filter all of the content specified in the tags field as a AND:

```
search=foreignId:d0c41422-acfa-4e4b-a9db-8c06b6860f3f, tags:SiteRef +\""TY0033"\" + BlockRef + \""00"\" + Disipline + \""FABRIC"\"&searchMode=all&queryType=full
```

and what it brings back (which is wrong as you can see from the BlockRef, though if I pass CN0001, it brings the correct values):

```
"foreignId": "d0c41422-acfa-4e4b-a9db-8c06b6860f3f",
        "description": "Health & Safety Eire - Site Photo - TY0033-01- 
FABRIC-005",
        "fileName": "TY0033-01-FABRIC-005",
        "fileExtension": ".jpg",
        "createdAt": "26/11/2018 02:00:24",
        "tags": "[{\"TagName\":\"SiteRef\",\"Value\":\"TY0033\"},{\"TagName\":\"BlockRef\",\"Value\":\"01\"},{\"TagName\":\"Disipline\",\"Value\":\"FABRIC\"},{\"TagName\":\"PhotoNumber\",\"Value\":\"005\"}]",
        "longitude": 0,
        "latitude": 0
```

95% of the time this is working perfectly, however the other 5% of the time, the images comes back incorrect, as Azure search has given the incorrect details.

I have checked and it seems to be because it is not respecting the multiplicity of the search terms. I am new to Azure Search, so I am wondering if I am doing it correctly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Index Definition:

[Index Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StrWf.png)

Edit: Updated Post with index definition

Comment: Can you share your index definition?

Comment: Hi Jacob, I have edited the OP with the index definition, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query you check if `foreignId` is equal to `d0c41422-acfa-4e4b-a9db-8c06b6860f3f` and `tags` field contains `SiteRef` and if any searchable field contains `TY0033`, `BlockRef`, `00`, `Disipline` and `FABRIC`. In your case all fields are searchable. Thus:

`forignId` matches
`tags` contains `SiteRef`
`TY0033`, `BlockRef`, `Disipline` and `FABRIC` are in tags field
`00` is in createdAt field, as standard Lucene analyzer tokenizes `"26/11/2018 02:00:24"` into `26,11,2018,02,00,24`

In order to search in tags field you should rewrite your query as follows:

`search=foreignId:d0c41422-acfa-4e4b-a9db-8c06b6860f3f AND tags:(SiteRef AND \""TY0033"\" AND BlockRef AND \""00"\" AND Disipline AND \""FABRIC"\")&searchMode=all&queryType=full`

It might be worthwhile to use [proximity search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search#bkmk_proximity) to make sure you correlate occurrences field/value pairs, e.g.: `BlockRef` and `00` e.g., `"BlockRef 00"~1`

Comment: Thank you Jacob. This has worked perfectly and my code is now pulling back the correct images related to the inputs. I will look into proximity searching as honestly that is something that I did not think would go together with this. Thanks for looking into this for me.

Comment: for anybody wanting to use this with the Azure SDK, pass the search as foreignId:d0c41422-acfa-4e4b-a9db-8c06b6860f3f AND tags:(SiteRef AND \""TY0033"\" AND BlockRef AND \""00"\" AND Disipline AND \""FABRIC"\") and put searchMode and queryType separately as search parameters. I spent a lot of the morning trying to figure out why it was pulling everything back correctly in Azure Search Explorer and pulling all the records back and not filtering them in Azure Search SDK and that was my blunder!